# Failed to download reposistory information

Tags: 12.04, repository

I keep getting this failed message and I don't know how to fix it.  These are the details in the error:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Is your PC connected to internet properly?

Comment: Your question may have an answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists